# Another VirtualBox screen size problem

Tags: virtualbox, display-resolution

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 in VirtualBox 5.0.14, and got the usual problem of only being able to get 640x480 screen resolution.

I ran
`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms`, restarted virtual box; no change.

I ran Xdiagnose with all diagnostic options checked - now I have a choice of 640x480 and 1024x768. Well, that's better, but still not good enough.

I go to System Settings | Software & Updates | Additional drivers, and under InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH: VirtualBox Graphics Adapter select "Using x86 virtualisation solution-X11 guest utilities from virtual-guest-x11 (proprietary)" and click apply. The computer thinks about it for a few moments, then changes my selection back to "Do not use the device".

So what next? How do I get bigger screen sizes?

Comment: You may have not yet [installed the guest additions completely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm) - they need the installer script to be run in the guest OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to install the guest additions (and I suspect that yours are not installed correctly) is to run:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
```

Then install from:

```
Device -> Install Guest Additions
```

on the VirtualBox running as guest. Newer versions of VirtualBox will actually differ slightly:

```
Device -> Insert Guest Additions CD Image...
```

If the installer cannot find the iso it is here: `/usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso`.

**Reference:**

- [VirtualBox/GuestAdditions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/GuestAdditions)